# Running frequencies - variable input limit

Tags: spss

Using SPSS v18 and would like to know is it possible to run more than 500 variables under the Analyze-> Descriptive Statistics-> Frequencies option?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you really want to do that, assuming that you have enough memory, but the dialog box limits you to 500.

Comment: I've got plenty of memory and looking at the file the number of variables to be run is less than a 1000. So, how do I go about allowing more than 500 variables?

Answer (score 0):

@Atwp67. If you go to `Analyze -> Descriptive Statistics -> Frequencies` a dialog box will open, In that select any one variable from the variables list which you want and the additional options which you need, then instead of clicking `OK` button , you click `paste` button that will generate the syntax.For example i have selected one variable(CLUSTER_NAME) from my data and some statistical options, and code will look like this

```
FREQUENCIES 
VARIABLES=
CLUSTER_NAME
/STATISTICS=STDDEV MINIMUM MAXIMUM MEAN
/ORDER=ANALYSIS.
```

After this you can add the variables which you want to add in the syntax.This won't limit you up to 500 variables, you can add any number of variables.